# Can't import AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I was transitioning my app from GCM to Firebase for push notifications which involved changing some dependencies. I changed the gcm dependency to firebase and tried to sync the projec, but after syncing I found that all my classes which had implemented AppCompatActivity were unable to resolve AppCompatActivity, and the import statement was greyed out.

[image]

I've never had problems with AppCompatActivity before, and I know AndroidStudio can be buggy sometimes so I'm assuming this is an AS issue rather than something I'm doing wrong. Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project multiple times, restarting AS... no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my appcompat library version from 21.0.+ to 24.2.1. This fixed the issue

Comment: Also make sure to match that version for all the other support libraries